# Element property to change by aspect-ratio of browser window

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive, viewport, aspect-ratio

I would like to change the height of the main container of my website (a div) from a certain value to another value when the aspect ratio of the browser window falls below 5/3.

I tried it with `@media (max-aspect-ratio: 5/3)`, but the browsers don't take this rule into consideration. In Chrome, when you switch to inspect mode, you can see it skips the rule. The case is not that it sees the `@media` query but overlooks the commands in it because of command priorities, but doesn't even see the query. If you add a rule like `@media (max-height:1024px)` you can see in inspector mode that the `@media...` rule is put into the command list. However it completely skips the `@media...aspect-ratio...` line, just as it was not written there. It is not because of the rest of the code, but the browser itself overlooks the query.

Any idea to solve this anyhow?

```
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 5/3) {
  .container {
     height:800px
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually works, see the following snippet.

Your problem is probably elsewhere

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 5/3) {
  div {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div >test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve this problem. It was an editor error not a code error. I am building my site at Weebly, and I noticed that inspite of that I wrote "5/3" into the editor and saved it, the system only saved "5" and not the "/3" part. So in the css the output site used  "(max-aspect-ratio: 5)" was written. That's why it didn't work. I reported this bug to their technical team.